# How to measure distances in a JPEG

Tags: logo, images

Probably a fairly simple problem, but I'm a noob at this: We've got a logo with my band, looks like this:

> [image: logo]

and we would like to use some fluorescent tape or whatnot to create a shiny logo to use as a prop on stage and we would like to use this jpeg as a blueprint for measurements so that we can recreate it in real life.

Is there any tool I can use for this, preferably nothing too complicated?

Comment: Do you have an example (or something similar) to what you'd like to achieve? Can you please include it?

Answer (score 1):

If I had to do that job manually, I would draw the negative logo with a black permanent marker on a [glow-in-the-dark vinyl](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/glow-in-the-dark-vinyl-glows_60811101122.html?spm=a2700.details.maylikeexp.5.2485673c3qVbDw) through an overhead projector, and finally cut out the triangle shapes. I would stick the six triangles in methacrylate pieces with holes and screws to be able to place them anywhere.

There's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RTI3yW6f1Q) about how to make a homemade overhead projector.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Digital printing on an adhesive vinyl will be the fastest way. With this JPG you don't need any measurements, just tell the printer person the final size.

Comment: If you have access to a video projector then you can use it in the same way, though connected to a computer.

Comment: Thanks guys! Last night I embarrassingly realized the easiest thing I can do is simply PRINT the picture and measure it real life (still blushing), but thanks for your time adn tips anyway, this one especially, I vastly appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to make something big enough to be seen on a stage. If so, there are certainly ways to go about it.

One simple method without any special equipment, is to use a grid system to make an enlargement. Here are the steps:

1. Draw a grid over your image.  You don't even need to use a computer specifically. All you really need is a small print of your logo. You can draw the grid with a pencil and a ruler.

Something like this shown below, which I will now refer to as the original image.

[image]

2. Then reproduce the same square grid, drawn in pencil, but with larger squares as big as you want, with the same number of rows an columns as the original image.
3. Using the original image as a guide, copy each quare onto the larger size grid image, drawing it one square at a time,
4. Erase the pencil grid marks when you have finished

Comment: Thanks guys! Last night I embarrassingly realized the easiest thing I can do is simply PRINT the picture and measure it real life (still blushing), but thanks for your time adn tips anyway, I vastly appreciate it! :)